# Checking whether a number is a perfect square or not.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

I was given to tell whether $945729$ is perfect square or not. I used the concept that

> No number can be a perfect square unless its digital root is $1$, $4$, $7$,
> or $9$.

Digital root of $945729=9$ but still it is not a perfect square. What am I missing here? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You’ve determined that your number is divisible by 9. So, divide it by 9: this doesn’t change its nature as a perfect square or not, since 9 itself is a square. Then repeat the check of digital root.

Comment: Perhaps you’re confused by the condition: if the digital root isn’t 1,4,7,9, the number can’t be a perfect square. But if the digital root *is* one of those numbers, this doesn’t mean that the number is a perfect square. Think of 7 itself, or 13.

Comment: Just compute that $973^2=946729$ and be done with it. If you don't see why that suffices, please also compute $972^2$. Alon Amit's suggestion also works, but in general you may end up with another similar question.

Comment: Then what is the easiest way to find whether the number is a perfect square or not. In competitive examinations they give big numbers like this and ask for checking this. At that time we can't just go with conventional method. Also the digital root is not a solid way to determine as I am seeing with this number.

Comment: It's divisible by $3^3$ but not $3^4$. This is easily checked by separately considering $945$ & $729$.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here?

A number is a perfect square is a sufficient but unnecessary condition of that the digital root is 1, 4, 7, or 9, so it could only tell you that if a number's digital root is NOT 1, 4, 7, or 9, it is NOT a prefect square.

First, the digital root is that the remainder upon division by 9 (except when the digital root is 9),

$(9k+0)^2\ mod\ 9 = 0$ (or to say 9?)

$(9k+1)^2\ mod\ 9 = 1$

$(9k+2)^2\ mod\ 9 = 4$

$(9k+3)^2\ mod\ 9 = 0$

$(9k+4)^2\ mod\ 9 = 7$

$(9k+5)^2\ mod\ 9 = 7$

...

You see, that's how 0,1,4,7,9 comes, but the reverse is not feasible because it's mod here, like 7 is not a perfect square itself.

> Then what is the easiest way to find whether the number is a perfect square or not.

Finding square roots by hand may be helped.

Perfect square trinomial could helped if number is too big,

You could check it out at [Calculate A Square Root](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-a-Square-Root-by-Hand), the 2nd method on it, this might not be easy but should be useful for competitive examinations in my opinion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was "what am I missing here?"